# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

При контакте с кислородом алюминиевые сплавы можно применять при температурах не выше 470 К (,) в конструкциях с давлением до 20 МПа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, так как "при температурах не выше 470 К" и  "в конструкциях с давлением до 20 МПа" - это не однородные члены предложения , они отвечают на разные вопросы

Comment: Спасибо большое.